# How to make a function that returns a 2-dimensional array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to make this function. The parameter suppose to be a random `N*N` array. And it should returns a `(N-1)*(N-1)` array. How can I do this?

```
int** SubMatrix(int** matrix){
    int** submatrix=new int*[size-1];
        ................................
        ................................
        return submatrix;
}
```

Is this code correct?

Besides, say in the main function, I already have this array

```
x={{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};
```

How do I call the function?

Calling:

```
int y[2][2]=SubMatrix[x]
```

is wrong and

```
int** y=SubMatrix[x]
```

is also wrong...

Comment: Is N a known constant, or can change at runtime? In other words, does it have to handle any size input array?

Comment: You should have a look at c++ basic syntax. A function should be called like `int** y = SubMatrix(x)`

Comment: Is that function signature fixed?  If you can change that signature, there are much better ways to do this.

Comment: ideally the size should be variable. But I don't know how to define it even if the size is fixed. You cannot declare like int f[][]() right?

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no way to keep track of an array's size in C++ (only the amount of memory allocated). So, it is necessary that the `size` of the array be passed as a parameter or be global. I make this assumption in the following declaration:

```
int* SubMatrix(int** matrix, int size){
    int* submatrix = new int[(size - 1) * (size - 1)];
    // Do stuff
    return submatrix;
}
```

Second, if your matrix is square it may be better to use the declaration described above where the size of the array allocated is `(N-1)*(N-1)` (See Kevin Loney's answer [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-using-new) regarding matrix declaration on a heap); thus, the array is accessible as a matrix. Accessing cells will, however, require a bit of arithmetic:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; ++j)
        submatrix[i * (size -1) + j] // Element at [i][j]
```

Finally, the array returned by the function is now a matrix pointer:

```
int* matrix = SubMatrix(matrix, size);
```

The dimensions of the matrix returned are `(size-1)*(size-1)`

With respect to your example now:

```
x = {{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};
int* y = SubMatrix(matrix, 3);
// y is now a matrix of size (size-1)*(size-1)
```

---

If you really (really) want a two-dimensional array:

```
int** SubMatrix(int** matrix, int size){
    int** submatrix = new int*[size - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
        submatrix[i] = new int[size - 1]
    // Do stuff
    return submatrix;
}
```

Comment: but this way the return is a one dimensional array right? Is there any way I can make it 2 dimensional?

Comment: Sure, but it isn't necessarily "2 dimensional"; rather, it's called "jagged" because you have an array of array pointers which may be of arbitrary size. I've appended the code to my answer.